# How to store event log in Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-log

On an ASP NET project (C#) I'm using the System.Diagnostics namespace to log errors, warning and information.
Using Windows 7 I see that the log I've set for the project is under "Applications and Services Logs".
How can I set in code to create a folder and put it under "Applications and Services Logs[SOME FOLDER]\Applications and Services Logs", for examples?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

When creating your `Event Source`, specify a `Log Name`. It will become the "folder" in the Event Viewer.

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource("Source", "Log name");
EventLog.WriteMessage("Source", "Your message");
```

Be aware that creating an event source may require additional rights on the machine. In an ASP.Net context, I suggest to create a windows or console application that create the Event Source. Run it once as an administrator.

Comment: Yes thats is the way I'm generating events into a log, but that way I get a structure of: "Applications and Services Logs\\[log]" ...but what I want is to have a strucure of: "Applications and Services Logs\\[FOLDER]\\[Log]"

Like for example the one on "Applications and Services Logs\Microsoft\Windows\Dhcp-Client\\[Log]" on Windows 7 event viewer...

Comment: Downvoted this answer because I have the same experience as RedEagle.

Answer (score 14):

The logs stored in the Applications and Services Log section are the logs of custom event publishers as opposed to simple Windows Event Logs.

From this article [Technology Summary for Reading and Managing Event Logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399431.aspx):

> Applications and Services logs are a
>   different category of event logs than
>   the Windows Logs. The Applications and
>   Services logs store events from a
>   single application or component rather
>   than events that might have
>   system-wide impact. They have a
>   variety of names that are defined by
>   event providers.

Thus, you would need to create a custom Event Publisher. Here are a couple of articles with more information:

- [Developing Event Publishers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382690.aspx)
- [Developing Using Event Reporting and Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756956.aspx)

Comment: Awesome details!

Answer (score 1):

This is a new feature of .NET 3.5 and available in . Microsoft introduced a new library that is not too user friendly read about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671205%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). It says, most likely out of date, that these classes only work in Windows Vista, however I would hazard a guess that they are accessible in Windows 7 and Server 2008.

I didn't find code there to explain how to create a new hierarchy like you were asking for, however, I believe this in the general direction.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using a more generic log mechanism which provides greater flexibility? For example log4net. Then you can switch between log files and event log and also other methods whenever you want without changing a line of code.