# Creating an application and event logs in the "applications and services logs" section of the event viewer

Tags: c#, event-log

I have a .NET application in which I want to write unhandled events to the event viewer. I noticed that there is a directory called "Applications and Services Logs". I would like to create an entry for my application in this directory and write any unhandled events to it. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation.

Is this even possible? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751265/how-to-store-event-log-in-folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a log entry with this method :

```
public static void CreateEventSource(
    string YourApplication,
    string YourLogName    )
```

[CreateEventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

Doc: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a.aspx

Example :[Eventlog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx)

Comment: This API can create an event source in the classic Application event log. It does not help with "Applications and Services Logs", which is ETW based. The question linked by @Shoban contains the correct answer.