# in Event Viewer, Applications and Services Logs, how do i create a sub-folder using c#4 .NET 4 vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, events, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, event-handling

sorry, i can not find this here at so, via Google, and by searching MSDN.

eventvwr opens with a folder tree at the left that looks something like this:

```
+Custom Views  
+Windows Logs  
+Applications and Services Logs  
    et cetera
```

expanding Applications and Services Logs, i see:

```
-Applications and Services Logs  
   Active Directory Web Services  
     et cetera  
  +Microsoft  
   MyNewLog  
     et cetera
```

Please note that "MyNewLog" is an item created by a developer like you.  Example:  [Creating an application and event logs in the "applications and services logs" section of the event viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171155/creating-an-application-and-event-logs-in-the-applications-and-services-logs-se)

if you expand the "Microsoft" folder, it has a "Windows" sub-folder that contains additional sub-folders.

QUESTION:  how to I create sub-folders and sub-sub-folders so that I can nest my event logs?  i use c#4, .NET 4, and vs2010.
example:

```
-Applications and Services Logs  
   +customers  
   -vendors  
     -vehicles  
        FordEventLog  
        HondaEventLog  
  et cetera
```

thank you.