# Writing into Application and Services Log with VBscript

Tags: vbscript, event-log, custom-eventlog

In my PowerShell script, I'm using this cmdlet for writing into Application and Services Logs in a custom log.

```
write-eventlog -logname "MyRemoteSuite" -source "MRP" -eventid 100 -Message $Msg
```

It's working well. Now I need to do the same with VBscript... But EventCreate is limited to Windows eventlog. I've found also  [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751265/how-to-store-event-log-in-folder), I don't know if it's the good solution.

Could you tell me if writing into Application and Services Logs with VBscript is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your PowerShell command using VBScript's `Run` Method.

```
Dim WshShell : Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "CMD /K POWERSHELL -Command write-eventlog -logname ""MyRemoteSuite"" -source ""MRP"" -eventid 100 -Message Msg", 1, False
```

Comment: Thank you, and excuse me for my late response. Ok it's the only solution...